# Whats a word for guilt for not doing something you want to?

Tags: single-word-requests

e.g 
"What are you up to these days? What about your violin gig? Going good?"
The question filled him with ___________. Since Laura passed away, his violin had been catching dust.

*Here, central character is a violinist and used to love it and play at some point of time in past. But now since his wife is no more, he doesn't feel like playing. But the question reminds him of the times when he was in love with violin*

I hope I am able to convey

Comment: Almost an exact duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/417028/what-is-a-single-word-or-short-phrase-for-the-concept-of-knowing-you-should-d

Comment: Similar, but no good answer.  I would not close this one for that one.

Comment: "I hope I am able to convey" what?

Comment: I don't understand how this is a Question for ELU, rather than a thesaurus or even a dictionary.

Comment: Hey Robbie,
Can you explain? I'll try to improve from next time

Answer (score 1):

*regret* [definition](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20regret&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

> a feeling of sadness, repentance, or disappointment over something
>   that has happened or been done. "she expressed her regret at
>   Virginia's death" synonyms:   remorse, sorrow, contrition, contriteness,
>   repentance, penitence, guilt, compunction, remorsefulness, ruefulne

"Regret" captures a bit of guilt as well as sorrow.

Comment: Yeah, regret comes close to what I have in mind, but not quite. Regret seems to have stronger connotation

Answer (score 1):

You may use these words:

- Remorse
- Self-reproach
- Compunction

They mean pang of conscience or deep regret for wrongs committed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question would have filled him with **nostalgia**.

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nostalgia)

> Nostalgia is an affectionate feeling you have for the past, especially for a particularly happy time.

Comment: I feel nostalgia just covers the 'feel good' vibe about the past, but not the guilt for not doing it at present.

May be 'a mix of nostalgia and guilt' covers it

Comment: @someday My first thought was _chagrin_ but I changed my mind. I think there is a mixture of things going on, as you say. Maybe I will think of something better. Or maybe someone else will.

Answer (score 0):

When I think of nostalgia, it’s a positive feeling. Maybe ‘Nostalgic sorrow’?  By using the word 'nostalgia,' you bring about thoughts of pleasant times past. By using 'sorrow' you're indicating a sadness that comes from remembering the fond memories.